# Сделать фотографию и прикрепить к профилю

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Есть задача, необходимо создать окошко / кнопку, где можно сделать фотографию и прикрепить к макету, сохранить в галерее или отправить на сервер.
Каким образом правильно будет выполнять данную задачу? Заранее спасибо

P.S. Окошко для фотографии в поле "ivPhoto"

Код макета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragmentToolbarSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="21dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNickname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/profile_of_employee"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/foto_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickPhotoProfile"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLogin"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/name_of_employee" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Введите имя"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/family_name_of_employee" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFamily"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Введите фамилию"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/role" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRole"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/id" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код активности:

```
public class ActivityProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    PresenterActivityProfile presenterActivityProfile;

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    String currentPhotoPath;

    ImageView photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        photo = findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        presenterActivityProfile = new PresenterActivityProfile(this);
        presenterActivityProfile.setOnClickListeners();
    }

    public void onClickPhotoProfile(View view) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        galleryAddPic();
        setPic();
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            photo.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = photo.getWidth();
        int targetH = photo.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.max(1, Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH));

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```